# When clicking on link nothing happens even if href tag is given

Tags: html, jsp, href

- I am creating a enterprise search engine. I am using JSP. In that I
  have given links to the pages with 'a href' tag. When I am clicking
  on the link nothing is happening. When I right click on the link and
  select copy link address and paste it in another tab then it is
  taking me to the respective page. Can anybody tell me what is the
  problem? Following is my href tag

  ```
   <html>  <a  href = "<% out.println(obj.toString());%>"><%out.println(obj.toString()); %></a>
  ```

Comment: Impossible to tell with the amount of information you've given us. There could potentially be event listeners assigned with JavaScript that call `e.preventDefault()`. Also you should post the generated HTML, the jsp in this case is less relevant

Answer (score 0):

Like Juan said, you're providing too little information. However I have a little tip on the question itself: `<a href="<%=obj.toString()%>">sometext</a>`, use the neat, expressive `<%= ... %>` syntax may make your code look much better(and luckily enough, fixes the problem as well, cause one possibility for your problem may be the line breaks `println` generates. Replacing `println` with `print` is also a solution if my guess is right(and you refuse to take my advice on the neat syntax))